# No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int16' and 'System.Boolean'

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda

I am using a helper class to build an expression which I then want to pass to a `.Select()` call on a EF Core `DbSet` so that I can dynamically select fields from the database and ignore large fields that I don't care about.

The helper class looks like this:

```
public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, T>> BuildFieldSelector<T>(IEnumerable<string> fields)
    {
        // input parameter "x"
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

        // new statement "new Data()"
        var newExpression = Expression.New(typeof(T));

        // create initializers
        var bindings = fields
            .Select(x => {
                // property "Field1"
                var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(x.Trim(), BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                if (property == null)
                    return null;

                // original value "x.Field1"
                var memberExpression = Expression.Property(param, property);

                // set value "Field1 = x.Field1"
                return Expression.Bind(property, memberExpression);
            })
            .Where(x => x != null);

        // initialization "new Data { Field1 = x.Field1, Field2 = x.Field2 }"
        var memberInit = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, bindings);

        // expression "x => new Data { Field1 = x.Field1, Field2 = x.Field2 }"
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(memberInit, param);
    }
}
```

As I say, the expression this produces gets passed to a `.Select()` LINQ call on a EF DbSet.

This was all working fine but I'm now experiencing the following exception:

```
No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Int16' and 'System.Boolean'.
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedCoercionOrThrow(ExpressionType coercionType, Expression expression, Type convertToType)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression expression, Type type, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression expression, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.CreateGetValueExpression(Expression dataReaderExpression, Expression indexExpression, TypeMaterializationInfo materializationInfo, Boolean box)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.<>c.<CreateArrayInitializer>b__12_0(TypeMaterializationInfo mi, Int32 i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIterator[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`3 selector)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.CollectionExtensions.ToReadOnly[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.NewArrayInit(Type type, IEnumerable`1 initializers)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.CreateArrayInitializer(CacheKey cacheKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.<Create>b__10_0(CacheKey k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory.Create(IReadOnlyList`1 types)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Sql.DefaultQuerySqlGenerator.CreateValueBufferFactory(IRelationalValueBufferFactoryFactory relationalValueBufferFactoryFactory, DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.<NotifyReaderCreated>b__14_0(FactoryAndReader s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.NonCapturingLazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[TParam,TValue](TValue& target, TParam param, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ShaperCommandContext.NotifyReaderCreated(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TAP.Services.TourManagementService.GetReviews(String tourId, IEnumerable`1 fields) in C:\Projects\TheAdventurePeople\TAP.Services\TAP.Services\Services\TourManagementService.cs:line 322
```

I have not changed the code at all since it was working so I'm not really sure what's caused it. I've also not changed any types in the model class I'm using for the expression. The expression that's being build in this instance looks like this:

```
{x => new TourReview() {ReviewId = x.ReviewId, TourId = x.TourId, Score = x.Score, ReviewerName = x.ReviewerName, IsHidden = x.IsHidden}}
```

and the TourReview class is as follows:

```
public class TourReview
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TourId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Review Date")]
    public DateTime DateReviewed { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Score { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Review Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Reviewer Name")]
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
}
```

I did recently upgrade to .NET Core 2.1 and to MySQL 8.0.13 from 5.7 if that's of any relevance.

**EDIT:**
I've also just remembered that I've recently changed from the Pomelo MySQL connector to the official MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore connector.

**EDIT 2:**
I believe this started happening after I u[grade MySQL Server on my local machine. The new version seems to be causing problems with the type mapping. Adding `.Property(x => x.IsHidden).HasConversion(x => Convert.ToInt32(x), x => Convert.ToBoolean(x));` to the model builder resolves the problem but I don't want to have to do this for every boolean property I have!

Comment: What's the type of `IsHidden` in the database? MySQL's `BOOLEAN` is a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`, which could be carelessly mapped to `Int16`. But it also has `BIT(1)`, which should be correctly mapped to `Boolean`. (This might be a bug in the underlying mapping code that fails to take MySQL's peculiarities into account.)

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert. The type in MySQL is `TINYINT(1)`. Are you saying that `TINYINT(1)` might be the issue? I've also just remembered that I've recently changed from the Pomelo MySQL connector to the official MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore connector.

Comment: Just tried changing `isHidden` to `BIT(1)` in MySQL and that doesn't seem to have helped :(

Comment: You'll need to dig deeper into your EF model (`OnModelCreating` and suchlike) -- I don't use EF so I'm not clear on the details. It's likely the model has been created with an inappropriate type mapping and it's no longer looking at the DB itself.

Comment: No worries @JeroenMostert. It's weird because there's nothing special going on in my EF setup. The entity setup is as follows: `modelBuilder.Entity<TourReview>(builder =>
{
 builder.ToTable("tourreviews");
 builder.HasKey(x => x.ReviewId);
});`

Comment: MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore connector is pretty buggy (e.g., this exact problem: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92987); I'd recommend switching back to Pomelo.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The convention set by Connector/NET is to map `BIT(1)` to `ulong` and `TINYINT(1)` to `bool`; using `BOOL` aka `TINYINT(1)` is correct. Oracle's EF layer has a bug that breaks this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92987

Comment: @BradleyGrainger thanks. I switched from Pomelo for this reason: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53759714/5392786 Are you able to help with this?

Comment: @AndyFurniss From https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/717#issuecomment-446949171 it sounds like you originally kept Pomelo and switched to MySqlConnector. Did you then switch back to MySql.Data and MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore? What reasons prompted that change? Is the source code for TAP.MySQL available? You're in a complicated situation that's mostly my fault (https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/189)… the best thing I can think of right now is to pass a `DbCommand` into `SmartUpsert` and have it call `command.CreateParameter()`.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood the timing of comments and questions… I take it you've now switched over 100% to Pomelo and MySqlConnector and this has resolved these problems. Definitely a on that solution from me (compared to trying to mix the two libraries).

Comment: @BradleyGrainger No worries! Yes your latest comment is correct. The guy from Pomelo recommended switching over to MySqlConnector entirely so that's what I've done and it seems to be all good now :). Thanks again for your assistance.