# MySqlParameter type conflict when using Entity Framework with Pomelo

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a DAL.EntityFramework project which has the `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` package installed. I also have a DAL.MySQL package which has the MySql.Data package installed. This second project is for general MySQL stuff which is not related to EntityFramework.

In DAL.EntityFramework I have a method which is utilising ADO.NET so that I can perform a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` operation against my database (which isn't available otherwise).

```
public async Task<int> SmartUpsert(UserDetails user)
{
    var dbQuery = this.queryProvider.SmartUpsert(user);

    using (var command = this.Context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = dbQuery.Query;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddRange(dbQuery.Params.ToArray());

        this.Context.Database.OpenConnection();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        this.Context.Database.CloseConnection();

        return Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@Output"].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

`queryProvider` is injected into the class and the implementation is in TAP.MySQL. This is used to provide the provider-specific SQL that's needed without typing the EF project to a particular SQL provider. It also creates the parameter collection (as these are provider-specific too).

```
public DbQuery SmartUpsert(UserDetails user)
{
    var query = new DbQuery
    {
        Query = "SmartUpsertUserDetails"
    };

    var sqlParams = new List<MySqlParameter>()
    {
        new MySqlParameter("@id", user.UserId),
        new MySqlParameter("@title", user.Title),
        new MySqlParameter("@name", user.Name),
        new MySqlParameter("@surname", user.Surname),
        new MySqlParameter("@email", user.Email)
    };

    var outputParam = new MySqlParameter();
    outputParam.ParameterName = "@result";
    outputParam.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
    outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    sqlParams.Add(outputParam);

    query.Params = sqlParams;

    return query;
}
```

When running this code, it fails on the `command.Parameters.AddRange(dbQuery.Params.ToArray());` line with the following exception:

> [A]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter cannot be cast to
>   [B]MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter. Type A originates from
>   'MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Users\Andy.nuget\packages\mysql.data\8.0.13\lib\netcoreapp2.0\MySql.Data.dll'.
>   Type B originates from 'MySqlConnector, Version=0.47.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d33d3e53aa5f8c92' in the context
>   'Default' at location
>   'C:\Users\Andy.nuget\packages\mysqlconnector\0.47.1\lib\netcoreapp2.1\MySqlConnector.dll'.

It seems that it's getting confused between the MySqlParameter in the MySqlConnector package that comes with `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` and the MySqlParameter in MySql.Data installed on my DAL.MySQL project.

What am I to do in this scenario? I'm not entirely sure why Pomelo is using duplicates of existing MySql classes but whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pomelo](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) is using [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) instead of Oracle’s own package. The benefits of this are outlined on the [MySqlConnector project site](https://mysqlconnector.net/):

> ### Why use MySqlConnector over Oracle’s Connector/NET?
>
> MySqlConnector is a clean-room reimplementation of the [MySQL Protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html) and is not based on [Oracle’s Connector/NET](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net).
>
> #### Async
>
> - **MySqlConnector:** Fully asynchronous I/O
> - **Oracle’s Connector/NET**: Async calls map to synchronous I/O
>
> #### Development
>
> - **MySqlConnector:** Open and Collaborative Development on [GitHub](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector)
> - **Oracle’s Connector/NET**: Closed Development Roadmap. Code is viewable on [GitHub](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net), some issues addressed in [forums](http://forums.mysql.com/list.php?38)
>
> #### License
>
> - **MySqlConnector:** The MIT License
> - **Oracle’s Connector/NET**: [GPLv2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html) with [FOSS Exception](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/foss-exception/); or [commercial license](https://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem/)

So basically, MySqlConnector is just a much better choice. My experience with Oracle’s own packages is also that they are slow to evolve and you have generally no clue what they are working on. For example, when EF Core 2.0 was released, Oracle’s EF provider was slowly updating and when they did release it, it wasn’t working properly. But the source code on GitHub wasn’t updated yet, so you couldn’t even tell what was going on there. Pomelo and MySqlConnector are much more open and generally nicer to use.

As per [this issue](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/549) reusing the same namespaces in MySqlConnector was a deliberate choice to act as a drop-in replacement for Oracle’s connector. Using both at the same time is not an intentional use case, although it [is possible to do so](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/189#issuecomment-285378373) if you really have no other choice.

For your project, this means that you should consider also moving to MySqlConnector. That way, you can resolve the conflicts easily.

---

As commented by [Bradley Grainger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23633/bradley-grainger), the author of MySqlConnector:

> There are a few parts of the MySql.Data API that aren't implemented (MySqlScript may be the biggest one, but it's very rarely used); most people find that it's 100% compatible with their use of MySql.Data. Check the migration docs here: https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/. You may need to change some connection string settings if your code relied on various MySql.Data behaviours.

Comment: Great, thanks poke. I had considered switching to `MySqlConnector` globally but wasn't sure if it was fully interchangable with `MySql.Data`, i.e. if it would have every thing that `MySql.Data` has. It sounds like it is a full re-implementation and is kept up to date (from looking at the GitHub page) so I think I will try to proceed with replacing `MySql.Data` with `MySqlConnector`.

Comment: As expected, this has resolved my issues. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @AndyFurniss I'm the author of MySqlConnector. There are a few parts of the MySql.Data API that aren't implemented (`MySqlScript` may be the biggest one, but it's very rarely used); most people find that it's 100% compatible with their use of MySql.Data. Check the migration docs here: https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/ . You may need to change some connection string settings if your code relied on various MySql.Data behaviours.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Thanks for that extra insight! I have copied that over into my answer to make sure that it’s visible and persistent enough :)

Comment: Thanks @BradleyGrainger . I'd seen that page and hadn't found anything that would cause me any issues. I really appreciate your guys' personal help on this!

Comment: In the event that one may have a use for MySqlScript, is there suggested workflow for using MySQL.data in the same project? The compiler in VS2019 blows up even if the MySql.Data class is specified in full (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection)

Comment: @T3.0 You cannot use both MySqlConnector and Oracle’s connector since they both share the same namespace. So when you have both packages referenced, it is impossible for the compiler to know which type belongs to which package. – If you absolutely need to use a feature that isn’t available in MySqlConnector, then you will have to remove the reference, or try to rewrite your code to not depend on that feature. This could also be done by splitting your application, moving the MySqlScript part into a background service that you could call from your main application.